# Navigation menu items conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

The problem is with 2nd and 3rd menu item. Whenever I click the 3rd menu item, the 2nd menu item automatically gets selected/active along with the 3rd one. However, this doesn't happen with other menu items.

**For instance(when clicking on the third menu item);**

```
<ul id="menu-1" class="navmenu">

   <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-464">
     <a href="#">list item 1</a>
   </li>

   <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-456 current_page_item menu-item-466">
     <a href="#">list item 2</a>
   </li>

   <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item menu-item-446">
     <a href="#">list item 3</a>
   </li>

   <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-448">
     <a href="#">list item 4</a>
   </li>

</ul>
```

Note: I have no clue where those different class on click are coming from.

I tried to add an active class on click and style accordingly but this didn't work. For instance;

```
JQuery(function(){
    jQuery('.navmenu li').on('click', function(){
            jQuery(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

    });

});
```

**Here is the css :**

```
.navmenu .current_page_item>a, .navmenu .current_page_ancestor>a, .navmenu .current-menu-item>a, .navmenu .current-menu-ancestor>a {
    outline: none;
    background-color: #7CD0AE;
    color: #fff;
}
```

It's strange why the class on 2nd menu item has current-menu-item and current-page-item indexed when i click on the third one.

Comment: My guess is that your css overlaps the links, I can't recreate your issue. Everything works as it should.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "it doesn't work"? Do you mean that the behaviour you expect to see for the "active" class is getting applied wrongly? If so, as pointed out it could be a CSS issue. (Your CSS snippet doesn't mention an "active" class at all.) Or have you inspected the elements and seen that the classes are not being applied/removed correctly? As far as I can see the JS code is fine.

Comment: @RobinZigmond actually I'm trying to overwrite with the above JS code  so that the class gets indexed active on click but that is not happening. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: sounds strange - do you have a link (codepen/jsfiddle or similar) where you can demonstrate this? The JS code as I said should do exactly what you want - so now I'm wondering if perhaps the 2nd and 3rd elements overlap somehow on the page, so when you click the 3rd one you are inadvertently clicking the second one as well? But it's all just speculation without seeing what you are describing.

Comment: Here it is;http://jsfiddle.net/brmz43nd/2/#&togetherjs=0daUHzbtS4

Comment: @Rohan - thanks, the link at first didn't work well because you hadn't specified jQuery, but I have added it. From inspecting the elements, the addition/removal of classes all works as it should. You can't see any actual change on the page, without inspecting the DOM - this is because, as I said, you haven't specified any particular behavioiur (CSS or JS) for the "active" class.

Comment: Beaviour in a sense?

Comment: @Rohan I just mean - there's no point adding/removing a class from an element unless that makes it do something different. Most likely different CSS styles, but could also be some JS thing. I presume this is part of an application where there is supposed to be an actual observable change to the page when the list items are clicked (that you don't have to use the devtools to see), but your example gives no idea what the intended change is.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the CSS to look at? A github or jsfiddle of the relevant code would make it lot easier to help.

I replicated what you have here, and if you hover over each list item you can see they have the correct link. Seems like it's probably in the css, or else something not shared here. 
 https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/814134/

The code below is because they make me add code when I link a jsfiddle

```
// find elements
var banner = $("#banner-message")
var button = $("button")

// handle click and add class
button.on("click", function(){
  banner.addClass("alt")
})

JQuery(function(){
    jQuery('.navmenu li').on('click', function(){
            jQuery(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

    });
```